# GraphQL: Provide more context to resolver from resolved stitched request

Tags: graphql, microservices

I'm running a couple microservices where each one as a graphQL layer that's being stitched together in another exposed service.
I'm trying at all costs to avoid direct communication between services but now I need some information to be passed into one service, that only exists in another service.

Does anyone know how to basically resolve some values from other service before proceeding with the request? These values shouldn't be exposed, but sent as arguments or some kind of context over to the service.

Summing up:

**Exposed Service** stitching from **Service 1** and **Service 2**.

**Service 1** needs property from **Service 2** but **can't communicate directly**.

Way from **Exposed Service** to resolve from **Service 2** and inject into **Service 1**.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont use same types on both of your services, you can try:

https://github.com/aeb-labs/graphql-weaver

Comment: Will that allow me to resolve something from one service and send it as context/argument to another service?

Comment: If you want to consume graphQL from Service 1 and send the result to Service 2 this is something you can handle in your resolver of Service 1 implementation by calling Service 2 with a GraphQL client like apollo-link https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link

Comment: But that's the issue, I want to avoid direct communication between services.